# Como obtener el nombre de un archivo apartir de su Uri en android?

Tags: java, android

tengo una pregunta hay alguna forma de obtener el nombre de un archivo (en mi caso una imagen) apartir de su Uri obtenida 
tengo el sgt codigo: y pues me gustaria saber si hay alguna manera de obtener el nombre especifico del archivo gracias.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (resultCode == -1 && requestCode == PickImageActivity.PICKER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        this.listaRuta = intent.getExtras().getStringArrayList(PickImageActivity.KEY_DATA_RESULT);
        if (this.listaRuta != null && !this.listaRuta.isEmpty()) {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("");

            listaImagenes.clear();


            for(int i = 0; i< listaRuta.size(); i++) {


                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),  Uri.fromFile(new File(listaRuta.get(i))));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                listaImagenes.add(encodedImage);


                sb.append("Foto"+(i+1)+":"+ listaRuta.get(i));
                sb.append("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En tu ejemplo el nombre parece estar acá: listaRuta.get(i)

Comment: Gracias amigo x responder, pero yo q sepa ese no seria el nombre sino la direccion q se encuentra el archivo o estoy mal?

Comment: Hacele un Log.d() y fijate, supuestamente es el archivo (con su ruta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nombre esta en el objeto File

```
File file = new File(listaRuta.get(i));
String name = file.getName()
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),  Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Comment: Si ya lo arregle era eso mismo que dijo usted gracias igual :) pero igual lo tickeare su respuesta como solucion.